# Cannot create s3 bucket with event to lamba attached to it in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I have a very confusing issue. I am trying to create s3 bucket with an event attached to it trigger lambda. Here is my code:

```
#s3-test-bucket
 ---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
project:
  Description: project
  Type: String
  ConstraintDescription: Any string
EnvironmentApp:
  Description: EnvironmentApp
  Type: String
  ConstraintDescription: Any string
S3BucketName:
  Description: EnvironmentApp
  Type: String
  ConstraintDescription: Any string
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub images-${EnvironmentApp}
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          -
            Function: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:test-
trigger-cfn
          Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
          Filter:
            S3Key:
              Rules:
                -
                  Name: suffix
                  Value: zip
DeletionPolicy: Delete
```

Now the problem is when I run it I get the following error:

```
    10:25:56 UTC-0300   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::S3::Bucket S3Bucket    Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

I have my lambda created before running the stack so what could be the cause of the issue?

Update: this fixed the issue :

```
  LambdaPolicy:
DependsOn:
  - Lambda
Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
Properties:
  FunctionName:
    "Fn::GetAtt": [ LambdaImageResizer, Arn ]
  Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
  SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you have allowed invokeFunction permission on your lambda function.

This looks similar issue as stated in AWS forum
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=167470